# jQuery Ui datepicker only building container

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Can't get my datepicker to build the calendar. It just places the container div in my dom.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $('.hasDatepicker').datepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="text" class="hasDatepicker" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I think it's quite similar to the example [HERE](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

I think i need some help. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using the css class `hasDatepicker`? As far as I know the plugin adds this class, after adding the datepicker, but it doesn't if the element already got the class.

Comment: change the class. as jquery uses hasDatePicker class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentionend in my comment, it doesn't work if you use the class `hasDatepicker`.

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y2bt7/). The input with class `test` works, but the input with the class `hasDatepicker` doesn't work.

So change your code accordingly:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('.dateInput').datepicker();
  });
</script>
```

and the html:

```
<input type="test" class="dateInput" />
```

From datepicker source

> /* Class name added to elements to indicate already configured with a
>   date picker. */ markerClassName: 'hasDatepicker',

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have seen that class in on other developer's code and i thought it was just a good name to give the same class to all the datepickers.

Comment: Yes, I would give the same class to all datepickers as well, but you just have to use a different one